# Is there an or/and operator in formal logic and if so how is defined and symbolized?

Tags: logic

I often use the `and/or` structure in sentences as it helps me to create many sentences more accurate than without it, which is generally important for me to do in any context.

I know that in formal logic, the symbol for `and/or` is just `OR` (especially when compared to `XOR` which is an "exclusive or" to declare that it's either X or Y but never both).

### My problem

I don't recall ever coming across a formal logic version of `or/and` and often wondered if it exists and used in the formal logic literature and have concluded the following:

- X `or, and` Y also
- X `or/and` Y `==` X `and/or` Y

In the first option `or, and` is mainly rhetorical and is a complicated way to say `OR`.

In the second example I just show how the order might not matter and `and/or` is equivalent to `or/and`.

### My question

Is there an `or/and` operator in formal logic and if so how is defined (differently from `and/or`) and symbolized?

Comment: It is unclear what your "opposite" means in general, and what the "opposite" of and/or is supposed to do in particular. If the "opposite" is negation then the negation of (inclusive) OR is just AND. In contrast, the negation of XOR (exclusive OR) is the biconditional.

Comment: @Conifold it was loikely a shadow of a thought I had in the past; I already deleted this. Perhaps you would like to answer about the `biconditional` - this part I believe I didn't understand.

Comment: XOR is true if and only if the terms have different truth values, the biconditional is true if and only if they have the same value, so one is the negation of the other. It is the same with OR and AND, one is true if and only if the other one is false.

Comment: @JohnDoea p or/and q translates as (p OR q) OR (p AND q), which is indeed simply p OR q. In ordinary language, p or q is ambiguous, and there is a general trend whereby more people get increasingly fussy in  the way the express themselves. As if talking to idiots.

Comment: @Speakpigeon I don't share the opinion according to which such a trend exists; I think that less place or mistakes is generally good.

Answer (score 2):

And/or is a rhetorical term used to indicate the “inclusive or”. Rhetorically, what you’re doing is indicating the inclusive use by adding extra redundancy; you’re saying “or, and also possibly and”.

“Or/And” is not a term in common rhetorical use, so it seems fair to say that neither of your above options applies if we’re going by either a “sense determines reference” or a “use-based” theory of meaning.  Or/and doesn’t have a natural logical translation because there is no existing body of language practice against which any formal analysis might be compared.

You could design some rule for its use and propose it to the world, but unless it catches on, what would the point be?

Language is more organic than that!